# logstash filter docker container name

Tags: logstash, filebeat

I am using logstash to filter by docker container's name to match the message differently for each container but is not doing this filter. Here it is my code:

```
if [docker][container][name] == "xibocms" {
    grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
    }
}
```

Any idea why is not entering in the condition?

Thanks

Comment: Please add a json sample. One possible issue is that one of your json element is in an array; in that case you'll have to indicate the index in your condition. For example for this json: `{"docker": {"container":[{"name": "xibocms"}]}}`, you'll have to use `[docker][container][0][name]` so that it enters the condition.

Comment: It was OK..but it was giving a grokparsefailure error...fixed..thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

would you try this way :

```
if "xibocms" in [docker][container][name] {
    grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{LOGLEVEL:level}%{GREEDYDATA:msg}" }
    }
}
```